# Seasonality reduction in a time series

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I'm working on a project in which there is a time series that contains calls number per antenna in a certain region. This time series has a seasonality of 24 hours (the number of call in a day at for example 1PM is very similar to the number at the same time the next day).

I've applied seasonality reduction by following this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/remove-trends-seasonality-difference-transform-python/) with lag-24 and I've applied some RNN models in order to predict future values.

I've some question about this application:

1. Is this seasonality reduction step mandatory? If I use original data
   how does this affect my prediction?
2. Is it normal that the NRMSE (Normalized Root Mean Square Error) obtained when applying the model on seasonality reduced data is higher w.r.t. the one obtained without this lag-reduction? Consider that with seasonality reduced data I got 0.8 NRMSE while on the original dataset 0.2.
3. Should I re-introduce seasonality after applying the prediction step? I mean, once I've computed y_pred by using lag-24 data, obviously these data are lag-24 differenced too, should I try to insert seasonality back? If so do you have any suggestions? Because the train/test split is random and I don't know how to reintroduced seasonality because I don't have the 24-hour before observation.

Comment: perhaps you should be hourly dummy indicators ,,,and possibly monthly dummy indicators while dealing with possible level/step shifts or possible local time trends . If you post your data I might be of more help

Comment: I can't for copyright reason

Comment: You say test/train split is random? You should split based on time, otherwise you leak data

Comment: I use [this method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for the split. What do you mean by leak data? Could you please point me to useful resources? Thanks.